# Javascript: Are objects returned by reference or is a new instance instantiated?

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have the following js function that handles `Date` objects:

`targetDate` and `referenceDate` are intended to be `Date` objects.

```
function validateDate(targetDate, referenceDate) {
  if (targetDate < referenceDate) return referenceDate;
  else return targetDate;
}
```

Now suppose we want the returned object to be a new instance and not a pointer to the same memory address as the input parameters.

In order to do this, do we need to replace the `return dateObjectInstance` with `return new Date(dateObjectInstance)`, or does `return` already instantiate a new object?

In other words: Are objects returned by reference or is a new instance instantiated?

Comment: You could check it using `==` comparison operator

Comment: `return` will not *automatically* instantiate anything.

Comment: Thank you everyone for clarifying this point

Comment: @zerkms : you surely wanted to say that the === operator was the way to test for object strict equality (exactly the same object).

Comment: @Vincent Piel: for objects it doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original assumption is correct -- without using `new`, the reference to the original object is returned.

And, as PointedEars points out, there's no such thing as 'returning by reference'.

Comment: So if I want a new instance, I need to `return new Date(dateObjectInstance)`?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new date.

Comment: @Chopo87: why would you want a new object at first place?

Comment: @zerkms There are situations where it is usful to leave the original memory space intact to be able to use that information in later calculations.

Comment: There is no “return by reference”. Object references are values, and the reference value is returned.

Comment: @Chopo87 This works only because `dateObjectInstance` is the only argument to the `Date` constructor. Per the [ES 5.1, §15.9.3.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2), the value is converted to `Number`. Converting a `Date` instance to `Number` is equivalent to calling its `valueOf()` method which returns the same value as `getTime()`, the *time value*, to which the time value of the newly constructed `Date` instance is set. You should not assume that this works for all constructors, although I would suggest that any good API should allow cloning objects this way.

Comment: @PointedEars, So you mean I should actually `return new Date(dateObjectInstance.getTime())`?

Comment: @Chopo87 No, but it is worth consideration. Passing the reference to the `Date` instance is elegant code here, but has (algorithm) overhead in the implicit conversion to `Number`. Using `getTime()` not only is explicit and self-explanatory, but also eliminates a possible source for error in implementations that are not conforming in that regard (although I do not know of one).

Comment: @PointedEars, Ok, so what you mean is that I cannot generalise the asumption that all objects in JS hava a cloning constructor. Good point, noted